# WebRTC RTCDataChannel - how to configure to be reliable?

Tags: webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I fired up a `RTCDataChannel`, and, by default it appears to be in unreliable mode.

I want to configure it to be reliable to get guaranteed packet delivery, but the `RTCDataChannelInit` configuration doesn't seem to have a setting for this.

```
dictionary RTCDataChannelInit {
             boolean        ordered = true;
             unsigned short maxPacketLifeTime;
             unsigned short maxRetransmits;
             DOMString      protocol = "";
             boolean        negotiated = false;
             unsigned short id;
};
```

Also, the `RTCDataChannel.isReliable` is a read-only property.

How do I configure the channel to be in reliable mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default is a reliable channel. See the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcdatachannel), fourth paragraph in that section.

Comment: Thank you. @Philipp is right, the default is reliable. To expand on this answer a bit more, the actual parameter is set as part of the `RTCMediaConstraints` (and not `RTCDataChannelInit`). I had accidentally set the `RtpDataChannels` flag as an optional media constraint which caused the channel to be initialized as unreliable.

Comment: RTP data channels are a legacy chrome thing (aka: don't work with Firefox), have been deprecated for almost two years and still lots of people stumble over this :-(